# Is there any way to get total count of passed, failed, flaky , total execution duration in playwright test automation using javascript

Tags: typescript, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, playwright

I am new to playwright test automation using typescript. I wanted to get total count of passed, Failed, Flaky count along with total execution duration. We need to add those details after CI/CD pipeline job execution in email body.

I am using below.yml file

```
stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  allow_failure: true
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.35.1-focal 

  before_script:
   - echo "$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA" "$CI_PIPELINE_ID" "$CI_JOB_ID"

  script:
    - |
      npm install ci
      npm install -D @playwright/test
      npm i -D @playwright/test allure-playwright
      npm install mysql
      npm ci
      npx playwright install --with-deps
      npx playwright install msedge
      npx playwright install chrome
      npx playwright test sample.spec.ts
      npm install -g typescript


  after_script:
   - cd utils
   - tsc ../utils/email.ts
   - node ../utils/email "$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA" "$CI_PIPELINE_ID" "$CI_JOB_ID"


  artifacts:
    paths: 
     - ./playwright-report/
     - ./Screenshot/
     - ./Reports/
            
    when: always
    expire_in: 7 days
```

Email.ts is the script that sends email after build execution

Comment: You will need a custom reporter that will generate your metrics into an email body, as there isnt a native report that does that. This link explains this exact thing: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/19360#issuecomment-1451468673

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 generate a json report by adding —reporter=JSON to your playwright command
https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters

Step 2
Modify your email script to something like this, so it can process your json from step 1

links for reference: [https://www.scrapingbee.com/webscraping-questions/playwright/how-to-load-local-files-in-playwright/#:~:text=You%20can%20load%20local%20files,to%20the%20path%20as%20well](https://www.scrapingbee.com/webscraping-questions/playwright/how-to-load-local-files-in-playwright/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20load%20local%20files,to%20the%20path%20as%20well).
How to read the json file generated.

```
    import * as fs from 'fs';
import { sendEmail } from './yourEmailSendingFunction'; // Assume you have a function to send emails

const reportFilePath = 'playwright-report/results.json'; // Adjust based on your actual report file path

fs.readFile(reportFilePath, { encoding: 'utf-8' }, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error reading Playwright report file:', err);
        return;
    }

    try {
        const report = JSON.parse(data);
        const summary = report.suites.reduce((acc, suite) => {
            suite.tests.forEach(test => {
                acc.totalTests += 1;
                acc.duration += test.duration;
                if (test.outcomes.includes('flaky')) acc.flaky += 1;
                if (test.outcomes.includes('passed')) acc.passed += 1;
                if (test.outcomes.includes('failed')) acc.failed += 1;
            });
            return acc;
        }, { totalTests: 0, passed: 0, failed: 0, flaky: 0, duration: 0 });

        const emailBody = `Test Execution Summary:
Total Tests: ${summary.totalTests}
Passed: ${summary.passed}
Failed: ${summary.failed}
Flaky: ${summary.flaky}
Total Execution Duration: ${summary.duration}ms`;

        // Assuming you have a pipeline ID and other details to send along
        sendEmail('Your CI/CD Test Report', emailBody);

    } catch (parseErr) {
        console.error('Error parsing Playwright report JSON:', parseErr);
    }
});
```